# How to avoid duplicate columns after join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes with the following columns:

```
df1.columns
//  Array(ts, id, X1, X2)
```

and

```
df2.columns
//  Array(ts, id, Y1, Y2)
```

After I do

```
val df_combined = df1.join(df2, Seq(ts,id))
```

I end up with the following columns: `Array(ts, id, X1, X2, ts, id, Y1, Y2)`. I could expect that the common columns would be dropped. Is there something that additional that needs to be done?

Comment: If you defined the join columns as a `Seq` of strings (for the columns names), then the columns should not be duplicated. See my answer below.

Answer (score 61):

The simple answer (from the [Databricks FAQ on this matter](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html)) is to perform the join where the joined columns are expressed as an **array of strings** (or one string) instead of a predicate.

Below is an example adapted from the Databricks FAQ but with two join columns in order to answer the original poster's question.

Here is the **left** dataframe:

```
val llist = Seq(("bob", "b", "2015-01-13", 4), ("alice", "a", "2015-04-23",10))

val left = llist.toDF("firstname","lastname","date","duration")

left.show()

/*
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
|firstname|lastname|      date|duration|
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
|      bob|       b|2015-01-13|       4|
|    alice|       a|2015-04-23|      10|
+---------+--------+----------+--------+
*/
```

Here is the **right** dataframe:

```
val right = Seq(("alice", "a", 100),("bob", "b", 23)).toDF("firstname","lastname","upload")

right.show()

/*
+---------+--------+------+
|firstname|lastname|upload|
+---------+--------+------+
|    alice|       a|   100|
|      bob|       b|    23|
+---------+--------+------+
*/
```

Here is an **incorrect** solution, where the join columns are defined as the predicate `left("firstname")===right("firstname") && left("lastname")===right("lastname")`.

The incorrect result is that the `firstname` and `lastname` columns are duplicated in the joined data frame:

```
left.join(right, left("firstname")===right("firstname") &&
                 left("lastname")===right("lastname")).show

/*
+---------+--------+----------+--------+---------+--------+------+
|firstname|lastname|      date|duration|firstname|lastname|upload|
+---------+--------+----------+--------+---------+--------+------+
|      bob|       b|2015-01-13|       4|      bob|       b|    23|
|    alice|       a|2015-04-23|      10|    alice|       a|   100|
+---------+--------+----------+--------+---------+--------+------+
*/
```

The **correct** solution is to define the join columns as an array of strings `Seq("firstname", "lastname")`. The output data frame does not have duplicated columns:

```
left.join(right, Seq("firstname", "lastname")).show

/*
+---------+--------+----------+--------+------+
|firstname|lastname|      date|duration|upload|
+---------+--------+----------+--------+------+
|      bob|       b|2015-01-13|       4|    23|
|    alice|       a|2015-04-23|      10|   100|
+---------+--------+----------+--------+------+
*/
```

Comment: actually the output DF *does* have duplicates using the following;  `val joined = sampledDF.join(idsDF,  idColumns, "inner")` . and where `idColumns` is  a Seq[String] containing the join columns

Comment: I don't think this works if the names of the columns in the two datasets are different.

Comment: What to do when out of 4 join exprs, 2 have different columns in both tables but 2 refers to same columns on both tables. rename?

Comment: What do we do when join columns of two datasets are different?

Comment: Assume if suppose, **date** column is in right dataframe too with different values. How can i left_outer join with getting the latest date i have among both tales? @sparkonhdfs

Comment: What needs to be imported to use Seq? I keep getting NameError: name 'Seq' is not defined

Comment: This will not work if columns have null values and its a null comparision

Comment: What if the common columns on which we join have different names in different dataframes?

Comment: What if the common columns on which we join have different names in different dataframes?

Answer (score 35):

This is an expected behavior. `DataFrame.join` method is equivalent to SQL join like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON joinExprs
```

If you want to ignore duplicate columns just drop them or select columns of interest afterwards. If you want to disambiguate you can use access these using parent `DataFrames`:

```scala
val a: DataFrame = ???
val b: DataFrame = ???
val joinExprs: Column = ???

a.join(b, joinExprs).select(a("id"), b("foo"))
// drop equivalent 
a.alias("a").join(b.alias("b"), joinExprs).drop(b("id")).drop(a("foo"))
```

or use aliases:

```scala
// As for now aliases don't work with drop
a.alias("a").join(b.alias("b"), joinExprs).select($"a.id", $"b.foo")
```

For equi-joins there exist a special shortcut syntax which takes either [a sequence of strings](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],usingColumns:Seq[String],joinType:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):

```
val usingColumns: Seq[String] = ???

a.join(b, usingColumns)
```

or as [single string](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],usingColumn:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

```
val usingColumn: String = ???

a.join(b, usingColumn)
```

which keep only one copy of columns used in a join condition.

Comment: Instead of select, can I drop the duplicate column?

Comment: Yes, but only via parents not with aliases.

Comment: How about an outer join?  Any rows without a match will have a null in one of the table's key columns, but you don't know ahead of time which one to drop.  Is there a way to handle that case elegantly?

Comment: @Darryl `coalesce` and drop both.

Comment: In the joined dataframe, i want the column name as something other than input table's column name. Is there any way to do this ?. For example : Instead of having the column name as "foo" which is being taken from "b" dataframe, I want to have the column name as "column_new". Something like this sql query : "select b.foo as column_new"

Comment: Can I do full join in Scala? I tried this way but it always discards the entry if the key is not in both df. So I did it sing spark.sql and then I have KEY column gets redundant. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

I have been stuck with this for a while, and only recently I came up with a solution what is quite easy.

Say a is

```
scala> val a  = Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).toDF("key", "vala")
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, vala: int]

scala> a.show
+---+----+
|key|vala|
+---+----+
|  a|   1|
|  b|   2|
+---+----+
and 
scala> val b  = Seq(("a", 1)).toDF("key", "valb")
b: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, valb: int]

scala> b.show
+---+----+
|key|valb|
+---+----+
|  a|   1|
+---+----+
```

and I can do this to select only the value in dataframe a:

```
scala> a.join(b, a("key") === b("key"), "left").select(a.columns.map(a(_)) : _*).show
+---+----+
|key|vala|
+---+----+
|  a|   1|
|  b|   2|
+---+----+
```

Comment: what does " a.columns.map(a(_)) : _* " do?

Comment: @Nick01 it selects the columns from 'a' data frame (see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909863/spark-select-with-a-list-of-columns-scala)

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use this

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("ts","id"),"TYPE-OF-JOIN")
```

Here TYPE-OF-JOIN can be

- left
- right
- inner
- fullouter

For example, I have two dataframes like this:

```
// df1
word   count1
w1     10   
w2     15  
w3     20

// df2
word   count2
w1     100   
w2     150  
w5     200
```

If you do fullouter join then the result looks like this

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("word"),"fullouter").show()

word   count1  count2
w1     10      100
w2     15      150
w3     20      null
w5     null    200
```

Comment: How do you add in a condition here, say `col("count1") > 10` say

Comment: I think you can do something like `df1.join(df2, Seq("word"),"fullouter").filter($"count1">10).show()` this. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: how do you import `Seq`?

Comment: I think you don't need to import anything. If it doesn't work for you then try this `import spark.implicits._`

Answer (score 7):

try this,

```
val df_combined = df1.join(df2, df1("ts") === df2("ts") && df1("id") === df2("id")).drop(df2("ts")).drop(df2("id"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal behavior from SQL, what I am doing for this:

- Drop or Rename source columns
- Do the join
- Drop renamed column if any

Here I am replacing "fullname" column:

Some code in Java:

```
this
    .sqlContext
    .read()
    .parquet(String.format("hdfs:///user/blablacar/data/year=%d/month=%d/day=%d", year, month, day))
    .drop("fullname")
    .registerTempTable("data_original");

this
    .sqlContext
    .read()
    .parquet(String.format("hdfs:///user/blablacar/data_v2/year=%d/month=%d/day=%d", year, month, day))
    .registerTempTable("data_v2");

 this
    .sqlContext
    .sql(etlQuery)
    .repartition(1)
    .write()
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .parquet(outputPath);
```

Where the query is:

```
SELECT
    d.*,
   concat_ws('_', product_name, product_module, name) AS fullname
FROM
    {table_source} d
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    {table_updates} u ON u.id = d.id
```

This is something you can do only with Spark I believe (drop column from list), very very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is using spark-SQL and wants to achieve the same thing then you can use `USING` clause in join query.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = List((1, 4, 3), (5, 2, 4), (7, 4, 5)).toDF("c1", "c2", "C3")
val df2 = List((1, 4, 3), (5, 2, 4), (7, 4, 10)).toDF("c1", "c2", "C4")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")

spark.sql("select * from table1  inner join  table2  using (c1, c2)").show(false)

/*
+---+---+---+---+
|c1 |c2 |C3 |C4 |
+---+---+---+---+
|1  |4  |3  |3  |
|5  |2  |4  |4  |
|7  |4  |5  |10 |
+---+---+---+---+
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to make column name different in both the DF before joining them and drop accordingly.

```
df1.columns =[id, age, income]
df2.column=[id, age_group]

df1.join(df2, on=df1.id== df2.id,how='inner').write.saveAsTable('table_name')
```

will return an error while error for duplicate columns

Try this instead try this:

```
df2_id_renamed = df2.withColumnRenamed('id','id_2')
df1.join(df2_id_renamed, on=df1.id== df2_id_renamed.id_2,how='inner').drop('id_2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner Join is default join in spark, Below is simple syntax for it.

```
leftDF.join(rightDF,"Common Col Nam")
```

For Other join you can follow the below syntax

```
leftDF.join(rightDF,Seq("Common Columns comma seperated","join type")
```

If columns Name are not common then

```
leftDF.join(rightDF,leftDF.col("x")===rightDF.col("y),"join type")
```

Comment: OP is asking about dropping duplicate columns after join I think you missed that point.

Answer (score 0):

After I've joined multiple tables together, I run them through a simple function to rename columns in the DF if it encounters duplicates.  Alternatively, [you could drop these duplicate columns too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405654/5196274).

Where `Names` is a table with columns `['Id', 'Name', 'DateId', 'Description']` and `Dates` is a table with columns `['Id', 'Date', 'Description']`, the columns `Id` and `Description` will be duplicated after being joined.

```
Names = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM Names")
Dates = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM Dates")
NamesAndDates = Names.join(Dates, Names.DateId == Dates.Id, "inner")
NamesAndDates = deDupeDfCols(NamesAndDates, '_')
NamesAndDates.saveAsTable("...", format="parquet", mode="overwrite", path="...")
```

Where `deDupeDfCols` is defined as:

```
def deDupeDfCols(df, separator=''):
    newcols = []

    for col in df.columns:
        if col not in newcols:
            newcols.append(col)
        else:
            for i in range(2, 1000):
                if (col + separator + str(i)) not in newcols:
                    newcols.append(col + separator + str(i))
                    break

    return df.toDF(*newcols)
```

The resulting data frame will contain columns `['Id', 'Name', 'DateId', 'Description', 'Id2', 'Date', 'Description2']`.

Apologies this answer is in Python - I'm not familiar with Scala, but this was the question that came up when I Googled this problem and I'm sure Scala code isn't **too** different.