# Spark Select with a List of Columns Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to find a good way of doing a spark select with a List[Column, I am exploding a column than passing back all the columns I am interested in with my exploded column.

```
var columns = getColumns(x) // Returns a List[Column]
tempDf.select(columns)   //trying to get
```

Trying to find a good way of doing this I know, if it were a string I could do something like

```
val result = dataframe.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*)
```

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using? 1.6.0 offers `def
select(cols: Column*): DataFrame` which should do what you want?

Comment: I am using 2.0.0. how would I make use of that, because I tried giving select a list[Column], and Seq[Column].  None of which worked, I saw that method too but I wasn't able to use it. How would I break up to the list in that invocation to make use of it?

Comment: `val result = dataframe.select(columns: _*)`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For spark 2.0 seems that you have two options. Both depends on how you manage your columns (Strings or Columns).

Spark code (*spark-sql_2.11/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala*):

```
def select(cols: Column*): DataFrame = withPlan {
  Project(cols.map(_.named), logicalPlan)
}

def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame = select((col +: cols).map(Column(_)) : _*)
```

You can see how internally spark is converting your **`head & tail`** to a list of Columns to call again **`Select`**.

So, in that case if you want a clear code I will recommend:

If **columns: List[String]**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
df.select(columns.map(col): _*)
```

Otherwise, if **columns: List[Columns]**:

```
df.select(columns: _*)
```