# Pyspark how to group row based value from a data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am need to group row based value against each index from below data frame

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+-----+----+-------+
|index|amount| dept | date |  amount |dept   |date   |
+-----+-----------+-----+--+---------+---------+----+
|    1|1000  | acnt |2-4-21|  2000   | acnt2 |2-4-21 |
|    2|1500  | sales|2-3-21|  1600   | sales2|2-3-21 |
```

since index stand unique to each row and date are same , i need to group the row values as below

```
+-----+------   +------------+-------+
|index|amount   | dept       | date  |
+-----+---------+------------+-------+
|    1|1000,2000|acnt,acnt2  |2-4-21 | 
|    2|1500,1600|sales,sales2|2-3-21 |
```

i see many option to group columns but specifically for row based value in pyspark
Is there any solution to populate the result as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally this needs to be fixed upstream (*check if you have joins in your upstream codes and try to [select only appropriate aliases to retain the unique columns only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46944559/9840637)*).

With that being said, you can create a helper spark function after creating a helper dictionary and column names:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from itertools import groupby
```

---

Create a fresh list with a counter:

```
l = []
s = {}
for i in df.columns:
    l.append(f"{i}_{s.get(i)}" if i in s else i)
    s[i] = s.get(i,0)+1
#['index', 'amount', 'dept', 'date', 'amount_1', 'dept_1', 'date_1']
```

Then with this new list create a dataframe with the existing dataframe and use a helper function to concat based on duplicate checks:

```
def mysparkfunc(cols):
    cols = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(cols),lambda x: x.split("_")[0])]
    return [F.concat_ws(",",*col).alias(col[0]) 
            if len(col)>1 and col[0]!= 'date' 
            else F.col(col[0]) for col in cols]

df.toDF(*l).select(*mysparkfunc(l)).show()

+---------+------+------------+-----+
|   amount|  date|        dept|index|
+---------+------+------------+-----+
|1000,2000|2-4-21|  acnt,acnt2|    1|
|1500,1600|2-3-21|sales,sales2|    2|
+---------+------+------------+-----+
```

---

Full Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from itertools import groupby

l = []
s = {}
for i in df.columns:
    l.append(f"{i}_{s.get(i)}" if i in s else i)
    s[i] = s.get(i,0)+1
def mysparkfunc(cols):
    cols = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(cols),lambda x: x.split("_")[0])]
    return [F.concat_ws(",",*col).alias(col[0]) 
            if len(col)>1 and col[0]!= 'date' 
            else F.col(col[0]) for col in cols]

df.toDF(*l).select(*mysparkfunc(l)).show()
```

Comment: Good stuff mate!

Comment: UDF is not recommended due performance. Pyspark makes things worse since doesn't work directly with JVM.

Comment: @SakuraFreak this is not a python UDF that I have used, but a  function using builtin spark functions. More reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance. Besides, this can only be dynamically done using loops and spark builtins (which my function does here)

Comment: Oh now I understood. Nice to know about helpers. Didn't think about using like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.. deppending on what you want

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, array, col

df = df.withColumn('amount', struct(col('amount1'),col('amount2')) # Map
df = df.withColumn('amount', array(col('amount1'),col('amount2')) # Array
```

if there are two columns with same name (like in your example), just recreate your df
(If is a join, there is no need... Just use alias)

```
cols = ['index','amount1','dept', 'amount2', 'dept2', 'date']
df = df.toDF(*cols)
```

Comment: HI @Sakura, i am not sure how to use select expression dynamically from 1st approach since i need to pass columns dynamically.. with the second approach, it giving error says "the number of columns does not match" even i removed duplicate column names as you suggested

Comment: edited the answer from expr to struct. And forgot to add asteristik in cols...

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have an initial data frame as shown below

```
INPUT:+------+------+------+------+
|  dept|  dept|amount|amount|
+------+------+------+------+
|sales1|sales2|     1|     1|
|sales1|sales2|     2|     2|
|sales1|sales2|     3|     3|
|sales1|sales2|     4|     4|
|sales1|sales2|     5|     5|
+------+------+------+------+
```

> 1. Rename the columns:

```
newColumns = ["dept1","dept2","amount1","amount2"]    
new_clms_df = df.toDF(*newColumns)
new_clms_df.show()

    +------+------+-------+-------+
    | dept1| dept2|amount1|amount2|
    +------+------+-------+-------+
    |sales1|sales2|      1|      1|
    |sales1|sales2|      2|      2|
    |sales1|sales2|      3|      3|
    |sales1|sales2|      4|      4|
    |sales1|sales2|      5|      5|
    +------+------+-------+-------+
```

> 2. Derive the final output columns:

```
final_df = None           
final_df = new_clms_df.\
            withColumn('dept', concat_ws(',',new_clms_df['dept1'],new_clms_df['dept2'])).\
            withColumn('amount', concat_ws(',',new_clms_df['amount1'],new_clms_df['amount2']))
final_df.show()


+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+------+
| dept1| dept2|amount1|amount2|         dept|amount|
+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+------+
|sales1|sales2|      1|      1|sales1,sales2|   1,1|
|sales1|sales2|      2|      2|sales1,sales2|   2,2|
|sales1|sales2|      3|      3|sales1,sales2|   3,3|
|sales1|sales2|      4|      4|sales1,sales2|   4,4|
|sales1|sales2|      5|      5|sales1,sales2|   5,5|

+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+------+
```