# PYSPARK - join nullsafe on multiple columns

Tags: python, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Let's assume we are having two dataframes, which we want to compare for differences with a leftanti join:

```
data1 = [
  (1, 11, 20, None),
  (2, 12, 22, 31),
]

data2 = [
  (1, 11, 20, None),
  (2, 12, 22, 31),
]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("value_1",IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("value_2",IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("value_3",IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("value_4",IntegerType(), True), \
])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
```

How can I nullsafe join these dataframes by multiple (all) columns?
The only solution I came up with is as followed:

```
df = df1.join(df2, \
    ((df1.value_1.eqNullSafe(df2.value_1)) &
    (df1.value_2.eqNullSafe(df2.value_2)) &
    (df1.value_3.eqNullSafe(df2.value_3)) &
    (df1.value_4.eqNullSafe(df2.value_4))),
    "leftanti" \
)
```

But unfortunately we have to deal now with a dynamic list of huge amounts of columns.
How could we rewrite this join in a way, that we can provide a list of columns to be joined on.

THX & BR

Comment: do you mean you want to pass a list of column names and create `(df1.value_1.eqNullSafe(df2.value_1)) & ...` this statement?

Comment: yes, that's exactely what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem statement, you want to create dynamic join condition based on a list of columns that one provides. We can do that using `reduce()` from `functools` module.

```
join_cols = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4']

from functools import reduce

join_condition = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [df1[k].eqNullSafe(df2[k]) for k in join_cols])

print(join_condition)
# Column<'((((value_1 <=> value_1) AND (value_2 <=> value_2)) AND (value_3 <=> value_3)) AND (value_4 <=> value_4))'>
```

You can use the `join_condition` parameter in the `.join()` directly.

```
df = df1.join(df2, join_condition, "leftanti")
```

Comment: This is excellent. You can use `from operator import and_` an then, `reduce(and_, ...)`.

Comment: For me this errors with `Reference 'value_1' is ambiguous, could be value_1, value_1`. `df1[k]` seems to reference a column name, not a column from that specific dataframe?

Comment: @user5233494 `df1['value_1']` is equivalent to `df1.value_1`. check if your `df1` has multiple columns of same name.

Comment: No. Using Spark 3.2.1 - maybe it's too old to support this?

Comment: @user5233494 - the syntax works on spark 3.4 and has been a standard since many many versions back. basis your error message, i suggest you take a look at your dataframe columns and lineage.

Comment: Oops, I had missed this was an anti-join, so it's not including columns from both dfs.
So for other joins it's necessary to remove the matching key columns which isn't straightforward e.g. `drop` silently ignores aliased columns.
Various solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944493/removing-duplicate-columns-after-a-df-join-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the list comprehension, for example like the solution given above, and you would get the same result

```
df = df1.join(df2, [df1[k].eqNullSafe(df2[k]) for k in join_cols], "leftanti")
```

Or my preference would be to use alias, so that I can immediately use the processed dataframe instead of creating new variables first. For example:

```
df = (
    df1
    .withColumn('left_or_right', lit('left'))
    .alias('left')
    .join(
        df2
        .withColumn('left_or_right', lit('right'))
        .alias('right'),
        [col(f'left.{c}').eqNullSafe(col(f'right.{c}')) for c in join_cols],
        'leftanti'
    )
)

df.sort('left.value_1').show(10,False)
```