# Convert Spark Scala join statement to Python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert the following scala statement to python:

```
scala> a.join(b, a("key") === b("key"), "left").select(a.columns.map(a(_)) : _*).show
```

Having trouble with the `:` and `_*`
I'm not familiar with Scala.

I need to implement the solution in this answer in python:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340781/2453657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Scala DataFrame API, the `select` method takes a variable number of arguments. In the method signature, this is denoted by a `*` as in the following example:

```
// Greet many people
def greet(who: String*): String = ???

// all valid calls
greet()
greet("world")
greet("alice", "bob")
```

The `:` token is used to give a hint to the compiler regarding the type of the argument and the `_*` in this case is used to specify that we are passing a collection as a list of arguments:

```
def people: Seq[String] = getPeopleToGreet()

greet(people)     // won't compile
greet(people: _*) // passes the collection of people as a list of arguments -- works
```

Not sure of how the Python API works, but from my experience I imagine you can either pass a single value or an array, so I believe the problem just doesn't exist in Python.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I needed to know.