# Spark - How to avoid duplicate columns after join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Extending upon use case given here:
[How to avoid duplicate columns after join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258506/how-to-avoid-duplicate-columns-after-join)

I have two dataframes with the 100s of columns. Following are some samples with join columns:

```
df1.columns
//  Array(ts, id, X1, X2, ...)
```

and

```
df2.columns
//  Array(ts, id, X1, Y2, ...)
```

After I do:

```
val df_combined = df1.join(df2, df1.X1===df2.X1 and df1.X2==df2.Y2)
```

I end up with the following columns: `Array(ts, id, X1, X2, ts, id, X1, Y2)`. `X1` is duplicated.

I can't use `join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String])` api as to use this api all columns must be there in both dataframe which is not the case here (`X2` and `Y2`). Only option I see is to rename a column and drop column later or to alias dataframe and drop column later from 2nd dataframe. 
Isn't there a simple api to achieve this? E.g. automatically drop one of the join column in case of equality join.

Comment: Is using spark sql an option for you?

Comment: It is. but I'd want to avoid manually selecting all fields from join. There are too many.

Comment: Okay, how many duplicate columns, do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, the best way to avoid duplicate columns is using a `Seq[String]` as input to the `join`. However, since the columns have different names in the dataframes there are only two options:

1. Rename the `Y2` column to `X2` and perform the `join` as `df1.join(df2, Seq("X1", "X2"))`. If you want to keep both the `Y2` and `X2` column afterwards, simply copy `X2` to a new column `Y2`.
2. Perform the `join` as before and `drop` the unwanted duplicated column(s) afterwards:

   ```
   df1.join(df2, df1.col("X1") === df2.col("X1") and df1.col("X2") === df2.col("Y2"))
     .drop(df1.col("X1"))
   ```

Unfortunately, currently there is no automatic way to achieve this.

---

When joining dataframes, it's better to make sure they do not have the same column names (with the exception of the columns used in the `join`). For example, the `ts` and `id` columns above. If there are a lot of columns it can be hard to rename them all manually. To do it automatically, the below code can be used:

```
val prefix "df1_"
val cols = df1.columns.map(c => col(c).as(s"$prefix$c"))
df1.select(cols:_*)
```