# Join in pyspark without duplicate columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This is reference to solution given in scala for thread 
[[How to avoid duplicate columns after join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258506/how-to-avoid-duplicate-columns-after-join][1])

```
>> a.show
+---+----+
|key|val|
+---+----+
|  a|   1|
|  b|   2|
+---+----+
```

and

```
>>> b.show
+---+----+
|key|val|
+---+----+
|  a|   11|
+---+----+
```

Expected output

```
>>> 
+---+----+
|key|val|
+---+----+
|  a|   1|
+---+----+
```

So I have to fetch data from dataframe "a"  when "key" matches on both "a" and "b"

One of the Solution given in scala is is working which is given below

```
scala> a.join(b, a("key") === b("key"), "left").select(a.columns.map(a(_)) : _*).show
```

Due to my no knowlege in scala , I am not able to implement this is python.
Kindly help me fix this python. Any other solution would be appreciated (without hardcoding columns of dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","1"),("b","2"))).toDF("key","value")
a.show

val b = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","11"))).toDF("key","value")
b.show

a.join(b, a("key") === b("key"), "leftsemi").show
```

[image]

Comment: how this can be done if I want my o/p to be  when key is not  matching . Here in this example  it's | b | 2 |